# hidden anchor tag when same records found

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I want to know if i insert like A1,A2,.... in a table and select them when same records found my anchor tag will be hidden?

```
                 for($i=0;$i<20;$i++)
                 {     
                ?>   
                        <input type="hidden"  name="ko[]" id="<?php echo $seatArr[$i];?>"/><a href="#" id="<?php echo $seatArr[$i];?>" onclick="myFunction(this)"><img src="images/<?php echo $seatArr[$i];?>.png" height="40" width="40" /></a>
                        </li>


            <?php } ?>
```

Comment: can you be a little more specific, i have no idea, what you insert, what you get and what you want to happen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that, you are getting values from a database and storing them in an array named `$seatArr` and you don't want to show more than one hidden input fields for the same value.

To do this, use `array_unique()` function of php and remove the unique values first and then continue with your coding. This way you can prevent from showing links to the same address again.

```
$seatArr = array_unique($seatArr);

$count = count($seatArr)

for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
{  
?>   
<input type="hidden"  name="ko[]" id="<?php echo $seatArr[$i];?>"/>

<a href="#"
   id="<?php echo $seatArr[$i];?>"
   onclick="myFunction(this)">

<img src="images/<?php echo $seatArr[$i];?>.png" height="40" width="40" /></a>
</li>


<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('a').each(function(index, element) {
        var this_a=$(this);
        if($(document).find('a[id="'+this_a.attr('id')+'"]').length>0)
        {
            $(document).find('a[id="'+this_a.attr('id')+'"]:gt(0)').remove();
        }
    });
});
```